Can you have "const const" after the function name?
I am investigating a block of code (that I did not write) that looks like:
customType foo::bar(void) const const {
    // baz
}

As far as I understand, the const const should really just be const. I can't find any reference to a valid usage of const that has two const keywords after the function name declaration.
Am I missing some valid, esoteric use of const here? This seems invalid to me.

There is no "very const" feature, so seems like just a typo.

"No, compiler, I really mean it this time."

Everyone knows compiler's don't listen the first time

Has the code block been compiling? gcc rejects it with an error, while clang only warns about it, but it does warn.

@chris It would be cool if this were a way to say you can't use const_cast to cast away the constness. That's kind of "I really mean it".

@JaMIT Yeah, I suspect we are suppressing the warning.

@JesperJuhl g++ considers it an error.  Other compilers call it a warning.  I wonder which is correct.

@DrewDormann I wondered the same, but it appears to be illegal

It's just a typo. There are no use cases that I know of for double const, so the usage of it twice is likely a programming error.

This is not a programming error. This is a common generic programming opportunity for cases like using T = const int; const T t = 0;.

@3CxEZiVlQ -- your example doesn't say const const. The compiler can merge redundant consts that come from different places, but the code in the question is not valid. There is no generic programming opportunity to write const const.

If you write const const after a function name, it is syntactically invalid because the C++ language does not permit such duplication. The second const is simply redundant and results in a compiler error.
The code should be like this:
customType foo::bar(void) const {
    // baz
}


Re. "... C++ language does not permit such duplication": for this to be a valid answer I really think you need to provide a reference to that effect.

@G.M. e.g. https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#1 Consider note 2, though

@Bob__ Right, and I think that reference should be in the answer (or any acceptable answer).

Thank you for the helpful comment! You're right that providing a reference would make my answer more authoritative. I'll add the link to the C++ standard as suggested.
